# Using presentModalViewController from an Array of UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, presentmodalviewcontroller

In my app there is a "main" UIViewController that holds buttons; once clicking on one of the buttons it opens another UIViewController (lets call it dataUIViewController) - when clicking on that dataUIViewController it open another dataUIViewController and so on until it reaches the last one and then all the dataUIViewControllers are released and we go back to the mainUIViewController. all the dataUIViewControllers are called using presentModalViewController.

I implemented it in a way where each dataUIViewController is created within the previous dataUIViewController (so the 2nd one is created within the 1st one and the 3rd is created within the 2nd etc...); I have a release method where the dataUIViewControllers are released recursively. Of course, I get memory warnings in case the machine is overloaded...

I'm now trying to build it in another way - using an NSMutableArray located in the mainUIViewController that holds and calles each dataUIViewController in its turn and releases it when done.

The problem is that presentModalViewController doesn't work on the dataUIViewController that I'm taking out of the NSMutableArray - it simply doesn't load; instead it goes to the next code line.

Anyone?

Comment: This "drill down" kind of applications is better handled by a UINavigationController. Is there any specific reason you are using modal view controllers?

Comment: It seemed easier at the time... now I'm eating my heart... If I cannot solve it in this way, I will start thinking of transforming it all to UINavigationController based, but I truly wish to avoid it

Comment: I transformed it to be based on UINavigationController and it works much better. I do prefer the visibility of the modalViewController but, hey, what can you say, you win some - you lose some...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason why your view controllers don't load.
It seems that the view controllers are not properly set up.
How did you initialize them ?

Answer (score 0):

I transformed it to be based on UINavigationController and it works much better. I do prefer the visibility of the modalViewController but, hey, what can you say, you win some - you lose some...